# Hide Image Button After Image is Uploaded in Typo3 6.2

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

Is there a way to hide the image upload button when image is uploaded.
I have singleimage field for this but when i add image i need to hide the upload button then.

Is there any TCA configuration for doing this...

Comment: Where do you want to do this? In the backend, in a TCA form in an IRRE enabled field? If so, try to set the `maxItems`-property to 1.

Comment: i need it in the backend.
and maxItems property to 1 didn't solve the problem for me because by doing this user can upload only one image that's fine but i need to hide image upload button too. thanks for replying.